# ¿Como llenar un select dinamicamente, AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, array, object

Ando llenando un select de los departamentos de una empresa de la siguiente forma:

```
$scope.selectize_a_data = {
                        options: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                title: 'Informatica',
                                value: 1,
                                parent_id: 1
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                title: 'Contabilidad',
                                value: 2,
                                parent_id: 2
                             }
                        ]
                };
```

**options.title** lo que contenga sera lo que mostrara el select. Pero este debo hacerlo de manera dinamica, es decir en title debo agregar un texto que venga de un WebService/departamentos.

lo ando haciendo de la siguiente forma, pero no se como insertar un objeto al arreglo **options** o que otra solucion podria darle ya que la estructura del objeto debe ser como la anterior.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:808/sistemaerp/public/ws/departamentos').success(function(datas)
        {

            angular.forEach(datas.records, function(objeto)
            {
                console.log(objeto);
                $scope.options.push(objeto);
            });


            $scope.selectize_a_data = {
                        options: []
                };
        });
```

Digamos que quedara de esta forma:

```
$scope.selectize_a_data = {
                        options: [
                            {
                                id: objeto.id,
                                title: objeto.departamento,
                                value: 1,
                                parent_id: 1
                            }
                        ]
                };
```

Ya que por cada objeto que encuentre el WebService debe ir agregando unos valores que contenga al arreglo **options[ ]**

El html lo tengo esta forma:

```
<div class="parsley-row">                                      
   <input type="text" config="ConfiguracionesSelect" options="selectize_a_data.options" ng-model="item.estado" name="selectize_a" selectize />                                        
</div>
```

Solucionado:

```
$scope.ObjDepartamento = {};
        $scope.departamentos = [];

        $http.get('http://localhost:808/sistemaerp/public/ws/departamentos').success(function(datas)
        {

            angular.forEach(datas.records, function(value, key)
            {   
                $scope.departamentos.push({
                    id:         value.id,
                    title:      value.departamento,
                    value:      value.id,
                    parent_id:  value.id 
                });                  
            });
        });

        $scope.ObjDepartamento['departamentos'] = $scope.departamentos;
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" config="confDepartamentos" options="ObjDepartamento.departamentos" ng-model="item.iddepartamento" selectize />
```

Comment: Estás añadiendo los datos a un `Array` `options` del `$scope` pero nunca añades este `Array` a tu objeto `selectize_a_data`. ¿Por qué mejor no añades lo datos directamente a este último objeto? Por otro lado, en tu vista tienes un `input` no un `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has probado de la siguiente manera?

```
$http.get('http://localhost:808/sistemaerp/public/ws/departamentos').success(function(datas)
        {

            angular.forEach(datas.records, function(value, key)
            {
                console.log(value.id);
                $scope.selectize_a_data.options.push({ 
                    id: value.id,
                    title: value.departamento,
                    value: 1,
                    parent_id: 1
                  });
            });


            $scope.selectize_a_data = {
                        options: []
                };
        });
```

Comment: No me ha funcionado :(, Muestra esto en consola: **Error: $scope.options is undefined**

Comment: A no perdon, debes reemplazar $scope.options por $scope.selectize_a_data.options.

Comment: Gracias. Solucionado (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Solo concatena los resultados que te devuelva el servicio al array de opciones en el `$scope`:

```
$scope.selectize_a_data = { options: [] }

$http.get('http://localhost:808/sistemaerp/public/ws/departamentos').success(function(datas) {
  let departments = $scope.selectize_a_data.options;
  departments = departments.concat(datas);
  $scope.selectize_a_data.options = departments;
});
```

Al cambiar `options` los cambios se ven reflejados en el HTML:

```
<select ng-options="department.value as department.title for department in selectize_a_data.options">
  <option value="" selected>Select Department</option>
</select>
```